# Find and replace a changing pattern with an extended pattern

Tags: python, regex, replace, replaceall

Im strugling with this regular expression
I have a simple string like this:

```
'<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE = 10 AND RPAREA = 1112</SQL>'
```

its number is changing and I want to replace

```
import re
text1 = '<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE = 10 AND RPAREA = 1112</SQL>'
re.sub('<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE = 10 RPAREA = '\d+,text1)
```

with this:

```
'<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE = 10 AND RPAREA = 1112 AND NAME EXSISTS NO </SQL>'
```

I'm trying:

```
import re
text1 = '<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE = 10 AND RPAREA = 1112</SQL>'
re.sub('<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE = 10 RPAREA = '\d+,text1)
```

There is thousands of different occurences of the number in RPAREA so search and replace will take forever.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this regex:

```
<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE\s*=\s*(\d+) AND RPAREA\s*=\s*(\d+)
```

Which uses capture groups to grab the two numeric values, which can then be used in the new string with `re.sub`:

```
sql_str = re.sub(
    r"<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE\s*=\s*(\d+) AND RPAREA\s*=\s*(\d+)",
    "<SQL>GEOMETRYTYPE = \\1 AND RPAREA = \\2 AND NAME EXISTS NO",
    sql_str
)
```

- [Regex Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rGnFuF/1)
- [Code Demo on Repl.it](https://repl.it/EBm3/0)